# How does project management certification (or lack of it) affect wages?

Tags: certification

#### Salary Surveys and Comparisons

In an attempt to prevent a proliferation of questions about the utility of certifications, or questions about which certification improves marketability or wages the most, let's collect relevant salary surveys here.

#### Why This Question Shouldn't Be Closed

Lists, especially lists of links, are generally off-topic on the Stack Exchange network. However, because this is such a frequently-asked question, it seems useful to have a single question to reference when duplicate questions are asked--and they will be asked, even if they're duplicates.

In addition, this question provides the community a single place to collect useful answers that can provide a starting point for **additional research**. With that in mind, references should be targeted and factual, rather than generic links or pointers to opinion pieces.

#### Caveat Emptor

It is important to note that the very nature of this question doesn't allow for a single objective answer (or even a set of objective answers) that will remain true in perpetuity, so *please* don't take any of the data presented here as the "final word" on the subject. There's no substitute for common sense or critical thinking, especially on matters related to statistics or important career decisions.

Comment: As a general rule, we should avoid coming up with too many list questions, even if they're made community wiki. With that said, if a post is going to be community wiki, this is perhaps one of the better examples of what one should look like. For more information on community wiki, see [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). I'll leave this open, at least for now, and see what the community as a whole decides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to keep this list alphabetical by survey title, to make it easier for folks to navigate. Your objective contributions are welcome in maintaining this answer as a community resource.

- [CSM or PMP, Which Cert Earns You More Money?](http://www.scrumology.net/2011/05/12/csm-or-pmp-which-cert-earns-you-more-money/), Scrumology, 2011-05-02
- [Salary for Certification: Certified ScrumMaster (CSM)](http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Certification=Certified_ScrumMaster_%28CSM%29/Salary), PayScale, 2012-07-13
- [Salary for Certification: Certified Six Sigma Black Belt](http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Certification=Certified_Six_Sigma_Black_Belt/Salary), PayScale, 2012-07-13
- [Salary for Certification: Certified PMP](http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Certification=Project_Management_Professional_(PMP)/Salary), PayScale, 2016-10-18